# react-native-ffmpeg: Native module cannot be null (ios) and null is not an object (evaluating 'RNFFmpegModule.enableLogEvents') (android)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, ffmpeg

I have a basic expo project that I've eject as `expokit`, and proceeded to run `expo install react-native-ffmpeg`. When then running `expo start` I was greeted with `Native module cannot be null` on my iOS device and `null is not an object (evaluating  'RNFFmpegModule.enableLogEvents')`.

After that, I re-read the `react-native-ffmpeg` documentation and added `pod 'react-native-ffmpeg', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native-ffmpeg/ios/react-native-ffmpeg.podspec'` to my `ios/Podfile` and ran `pod install`. Still no luck.

After that, I deleted the `node_modules` folder and `yarn.lock` file, re-ran `yarn`, went into the `ios` directory, deleted the `Pods` folder and `Podfile.lock` file and re-ran `pod install` and still had no luck!

The error is less than helpful. Any ideas where to look?

Comment: Well, it seems like the issue is either with expo or with some missing NPM module. I gave up tying to narrow it down for now and just switched to react native.

Comment: I've got no resolution for this. I just created a new react project and made sure I followed all available documentation and didn't get the error.

Answer (score 1):

i found one new receipt, worked to me:
https://github.com/tanersener/react-native-ffmpeg/pull/137

Need move file `react-native-ffmpeg.podspec` in `node-modules\react-native-ffmpeg` from `ios` directory to root of this module.